# Switching between two partial views in a layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two partial views that I want to load after clicking a button. It should work like this - the first partial view is the one that displays defaultly, after I click the button - the partial view switches to the second one. Once you click again on the same button in the partial view - the layout switches to the first one. I don't really know how to approach that problem - I thought about declaring a flag that would go from 0 to 1, but I couldn't figure out how to save that flag in a controller or in a .cshtml page so that it saves even if I refresh the page. The two partial views show in every page of my app - it's a sidebar.

Code snippet of my _layout.cshtml

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            @{
                int flag = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]);
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    Html.Action("LoadPartial", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    Html.Action("LoadPartial2", "Home");

                }
            }
                }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller snippet

```
public PartialViewResult LoadPartial()
        {

            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            var user2 = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            AspNetUser model = new AspNetUser();
            model.Email = user2.Email;
            model.Id = user2.Id;
            model.UserName = user2.UserName;
            model.PhoneNumber = user2.PhoneNumber;
            return PartialView("_ProfileEditPartial", model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try saving the flag as a session value, the following link shows Mircosoft's documentation on how to set up session state: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state. Once set up, you can easily set/get your value using

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("SessionPartial", 0);
HttpContext.Session.GetStringInt32("SessionPartial");
```

and it stays persistent even if user refreshes. Since you said the partials show up on every page of the app, set the session variable in the first controller method your app goes into, or as early as possible.

After setting up the session variable, create a controller method which determines what partial to return based on the session value.

```
public PartialViewResult LoadPartial()
{
    var flag = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("SessionPartial");
    if (flag == 0) {
        // set up model here
        return PartialView("_Partial1", model);
    }
    else {
        // set up model here
        return PartialView("_Partial2", model);
    }
}
```

Finally, in the view write some JavaScript in which you simply get and display the partial. On the click of the button, get the div in which your partial is stored, empty it of the past partial, and then load the correct partial by calling the controller method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonId").click(function () {
        $('#divId').empty();            
        $('#divId').load('@Url.Action("LoadPartial", "<YourControllerNameHere>"));
    });
}
```